# Как в aiogram 3.* версии зарегистрировать callback

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Мне нужно зарегистрировать callback с callback_data == "create_promo".
На просторах интернета находил примеры регистрации, но версия aiogram была 2.*
Как мне быть?

```
async def create_promo(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.answer("PROMOCODE")


async def register_admin_callbacks(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.callback_query.register(create_promo)  # callback.data == "create_promo"
```

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/